# mongochart getting db connection timeout when I try to start

Tags: mongodb, docker

I am trying to setup mongodbchart locally on y ubuntu pc, I tried all the steps provided [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/charts/19.12/installation/) , but still I am getting this below error.

```
mongodb-charts_charts.1.qyf0d5dg2hwl@coder-ubuntu    |  ✔ gitHash ('1a46f17f')
mongodb-charts_charts.1.qyf0d5dg2hwl@coder-ubuntu    |  ✔ supportWidgetAndMetrics ('on')
mongodb-charts_charts.1.qyf0d5dg2hwl@coder-ubuntu    |  ✔ tileServer (undefined)
mongodb-charts_charts.1.qyf0d5dg2hwl@coder-ubuntu    |  ✔ tileAttributionMessage (undefined)
mongodb-charts_charts.1.qyf0d5dg2hwl@coder-ubuntu    |  ✔ rawFeatureFlags (undefined)
mongodb-charts_charts.1.qyf0d5dg2hwl@coder-ubuntu    |  ✔ encryptionKeyPath 
mongodb-charts_charts.1.qyf0d5dg2hwl@coder-ubuntu    |  ✔ stitchMigrationsLog ({ completedStitchMigrations: [] })
mongodb-charts_charts.1.qyf0d5dg2hwl@coder-ubuntu    |  ✔ featureFlags ({})
mongodb-charts_charts.1.qyf0d5dg2hwl@coder-ubuntu    |  ✔ lastAppJson ({})
mongodb-charts_charts.1.qyf0d5dg2hwl@coder-ubuntu    |  ✔ existingInstallation (false)
mongodb-charts_charts.1.qyf0d5dg2hwl@coder-ubuntu    |  ✔ tenantId ('d4a588ea-6f66-4c9f-8356-69a5f079f641')
mongodb-charts_charts.1.qyf0d5dg2hwl@coder-ubuntu    |  ✔ chartsMongoDBUri 
mongodb-charts_charts.1.qyf0d5dg2hwl@coder-ubuntu    |  ✔ tokens 
mongodb-charts_charts.1.qyf0d5dg2hwl@coder-ubuntu    |  ✔ stitchConfigTemplate 
mongodb-charts_charts.1.qyf0d5dg2hwl@coder-ubuntu    |  ✔ libMongoIsInPath (true)
mongodb-charts_charts.1.qyf0d5dg2hwl@coder-ubuntu    |  ✖ mongoDBReachable failure: Can't connect to MongoDB at mongodb://172.17.0.2:27017. Too many failed attempts. Last error: failed to connect to server [172.17.0.2:27017] on first connect [MongoNetworkError: connection 14 to 172.17.0.2:27017 timed out]
```

I have installed mongodb on other docker with below commands

```
docker pull mongo 
docker run -t -d mongo
```

when I tried connection string from dokcer it is working fine

```
docker run --rm quay.io/mongodb/charts:19.12.1 charts-cli test-connection 'mongodb://172.17.0.2:27017'
MongoDB connection URI successfully verified.

Before starting Charts, please create a Docker Secret containing this connection URI using the following command:
echo "mongodb://172.17.0.2:27017" | docker secret create charts-mongodb-uri -
```

So I am stuck where would be the problem for connection timeout when I deploy mongo chart stack.

Comment: If both containers are created in the same network try with mongodb://mongo:27017

Comment: Getting MongoNetworkError: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND mongo mongo:27017